# Fast encrypt, slow decrypt method for NDB Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, encryption

I have unencrypted web request data (not under my jurisdiction) that I would like to quickly save into the Datastore so as not to slow down the request process.

The sensitive data occasionally is required to be opened by system users via the web. When a user makes such a request, it will require them to complete a reCAPTCHA before the decryption process starts and an event is logged regarding their behavior. Decryption time could suitably be up to 1 minute long for a string of between 10 and 20 characters.

Is there an encryption algorithm usable on GAE which is slower to decrypt than encrypt that would be suitable in this case?

I'm contemplating another method to alleviate the encryption time:

- temporarily store the data mildly encrypted with <del>MD5 & hash</del> quick encryption method, while a scheduled job iterates over any records not flagged as properly encrypted and economically applies very strong encryption (it would be acceptable for the user to be alerted that encryption has not yet finished if they tried to access the data immediately after input)

Assuming the above method is feasible, then I assume I can encrypt the pants out of the data for a few minutes, rendering it extremely costly to try to decrypt if data is compromised but system is not.

Comment: Would you need to decrypt the data after encrypting it? If so, MD5 will not do you good, since it is an one-way hashing algorithm. I am curious for why would you have such a requirement to decrypt the data for such a long time. Is that some security concern?

Comment: Thanks @IvayloSlavov, good point. The data does need to be able to be decrypted, so I'll scrub the MD5 part of above method.

Comment: It sounds like you're conflating time to decrypt (for someone who has the key) with time to crack (for someone who doesn't have the key). Can you explain more clearly what security need you have that is met by decryption with the correct key taking 20-60 seconds?

Comment: @svk, there is not a requirement for the decryption to take any length of time, but a lengthy decryption time will not be a problem if that is what the solution requires. I assume stronger encryption requires more time to decrypt, but am unfamiliar if there are any quick (CPU time) encryption methods which may fit the use case by taking longer than others to decrypt. I would also like to keep GAE costs down by taking time with decryption if possible.

Comment: Stronger encryption does not necesarily take more time to decrypt. That only applies if you try to crack it without having all the necesary data like the encryption keys. Sounds insane to take even 1s to decrypt a short string. Also, dont enctypt short strings, its easier to attack them. Pad them always to a minimum length us some random data (so its not always the same length either)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like conventional cryptographical methods should meet your needs, e.g. AES256. When it comes to crypto you should try to innovate as little as possible. Use well-established and well-trusted methods -- when "rolling your own" it's very easy to make mistakes, and you don't get the benefit of peer review from the academic cryptography community.

Make sure to benchmark how long the encryption with the strong algorithm of your choice actually takes before doing work to address the issue of the encryption blocking the request. Would a few hundred milliseconds' delay really be a problem?

If it turns out encryption is too slow, you still shouldn't compromise on the quality of your encryption algorithm. A better solution to this would be to perform the encryption in a background thread and continue with the request immediately.

Allot an ID in your database to the resource that is to be inserted in encrypted form, but don't bother with an intermediate, intentionally "mild" form of encryption before the "real" encryption. This layer would only be providing a false sense of security.

If a user attempts to access a resource that has not yet been encrypted, return an error indicating that the resource is still being processed (or that the encryption has failed, if applicable).

Make sure that there's no possibility of the encryption process failing or being delayed in a way that results in unencrypted data being kept around for longer than it should. If encryption can't succeed in a timely manner (because of disks being full / power failure / cosmic rays), the insertion must simply be allowed to fail and the unencrypted data must not be kept.

Comment: Thanks svk, very educational points and I shall test an AES or similar  implementation. Background threading it should not be a problem if the time does seem slow (initial concerns raised by a few SO posts regarding GAE/Python encryption times).

Comment: You won't be able to process the encryption in a background thread on a front facing request handler.  encryption is cpu intensive and it will just block the handler.  You may want to send the data to a resident backend and let it handle the encryption.